# Tabular data in Drupal: create a field with multiple attributes

Tags: 7

**Hello again**

What I want to do is simply like creating tabular form, that the user can edit attributes of each row.

In detail, I have a content type lets call it Website, this content type should contain predefined Stages and Processes. For each Stage/Process the user should be able to check as done, or enter a reference or notes, or any another related operations.

***As an Examples***

Feed the cat ---- (checkbox) ---- Reference ---- Notes

**So, how could I represent this tabular form in Drupal 7?**

**Is there any module specially made for this purpose?**

Hope you can help guys

Best and peace

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should look at the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module, which allows you to make groups of fields and reuse them in a content type like a single field. So in your case, each collection might contain the fields "stage," "completed" (checkbox), "reference," and "notes," and then you could use that field collection multiple times throughout your content type.